# Induction to prove regular expression

Tags: induction, regular-language, regular-expressions

Prove that is if *S* and *T* are any regular expressions over the one-letter alphabet, (for example: Σ = {a}), and if *n* is any natural, then the languages *(ST)^n* and *(S^n)(T^n)* are equal.

I have to use induction for this, and have to provide two examples of regular expressions *S* and *T* such that *(ST)** and S*T*  are **NOT** equal.

How would I go about doing this? I think my base case would be with the empty set for *S* and *T* and then my inductive step would assume that those are true, but then I do not know where to go from there.

Any help is great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas to get you going.

Words over a one-letter alphabet are distinguished only by their lengths. If $R$ is any regular expression for that alphabet, let $L_R$ be the set of lengths of words corresponding to $R$. The words in $ST$ are exactly those whose lengths are of the form $s+t$ for some $s\in L_S$ and $t\in L_T$: we could express this by writing $L_{ST}=L_S+L_T$.

What is $L_{(ST)^2}$? $(ST)^2=STST$, so the words in $(ST)^2$ have lengths of the form $s_1+t_1+s_2+t_2$, where $s_1,s_2\in L_S$ and $t_1,t_2\in L_T$. Conversely, if you start with any $s_1,s_2\in L_S$ and $t_1,t_2\in L_T$, there is a word of that length in $(ST)^2$. But

$$s_1+t_1+s_2+t_2=s_1+s_2+t_1+t_2\;,$$

so you can also find a word of that length in $S^2T^2$. Similarly, starting with a word in $S^2T^2$, you can find one of the same length in $(ST)^2$. Thus, $L_{S^2T^2}=L_{(ST)^2}$. But words of the same length over a one-letter alphabet are the same word, so $(ST)^2=S^2T^2$.

Now generalize this to $(ST)^n$ and $S^nT^n$ for arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$; you won’t need an induction argument, unless you’re required to prove that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(s_k+t_k)=\sum_{k=1}^ns_k+\sum_{k=1}^nt_k$$

for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and all $s_k,t_k\in\Bbb N$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$.

For the second part, there’s a simple example with $S=T$, both being just about the simplest possible regular expression that generates a non-empty word. For that example $(ST)^*$ generates a proper subset of $S^*T^*$.